# Does Haskell's foldi/foldt exist in Python?

Tags: python, functional-programming, fold

I know about the pythons reduce which is equivalent with Haskell's foldl but I can't find something similar with Haskell's foldi/foldt [Link_to_haskell_fold_examples](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Fold#Examples)

Comment: `foldi` and `foldt` are not standard Haskell functions. They are just two functions which are defined on the page you linked. Of course they can be implemented in Python as well.

Comment: thanks @interjay :) Just hoped to find something builtin (thought Python had it all) :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> foldi and foldt are not standard Haskell functions. They are just two functions which are defined on the page you linked. Of course they can be implemented in Python as well.

- comment from @interjay